# Proxmox VMs Fail to start on reboot due to unmounted drives

Tags: raid, proxmox

For whatever reason, I have to re-assemble my RAID arrays on boot, I don't know why, and Ive banged my head against my desk over that issue to much already, so I put the RAID mdadm commands in /etc/rc.local along with a `mount -a`.

My current challenge is, that the Proxmox VMs fail to start because their images are on those RAID arrays, and they are not mounted when Proxmox tries to start the VMs.

I was hoping that the Proxmox startup-delay option would solve this, but apparently thats the delay before starting the next VM, which if the first one fails, it just tries to start the second one.

I could put a dummy VM on the drive that Proxmox boots from, and start that one first, but this is not ideal, I do not want dummy VMs running, it's a waste.

My question is, does anyone know how I can go about delaying Proxmox from starting the VMs for just a minute or two while the RAID arrays are re-assembled and mounted?